# RavenDB Restore slow

Tags: backup, ravendb, restore

I've been testing our DR Process for a new application and am finding that RavenDB restore is taking an unexpected and unacceptable amount of time. I need to know if there is something wrong with my process or if there is a way of improving performance.

For the 70MB database I am restoring it is taking > 8 hours.

After stopping the RavenDB Windows service I'm using the following command, after reading RavenDB documentation http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/backup-restore

```
d:\RavenDB\Server>Raven.Server.exe -src "D:\Backups\RavenDB\2013-11-25_2330\MyDatabase\RavenDB.Backup" -dest "D:\RavenDB\Server\Data
base\Databases\" -restore
```

I get progress reporting like this:

```
Request #10,306: POST    -    72 ms - <system>   - 201 - /admin/backup
Request #10,307: GET     -    21 ms - <system>   - 200 - /docs/Raven/Backup/Stat
us
Request #10,308: GET     -     0 ms - <system>   - 200 - /docs/Raven/Backup/Stat
us
Request #10,309: POST    - 1,150 ms - MyDatabase - 201 - /admin/backup
Request #10,310: GET     -    32 ms - MyDatabase - 200 - /docs/Raven/Backup/Status
```

etc

But have not yet had confirmation of successful restore.

Comment: I've also been unable to complete this operation using the GUI.